# Check if MySql online server is reachable from local application in short period of time with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, connection

I have a **local** web application based on **PHP** that uses an **online** Mysql server.

I need to know when I can reach that server (when do I have internet connection, or when the server is shutdown).

I've tried this

```
$conn = new mysqli('hostname','username','password','db');

if($conn->connect_error){
    //offline action
}
else{
    //online action
}
```

which works but it lasts for about a minute to determine if server is reachable or not.

I was wondering if there is any other solution for this that lasts less than 3 or 4 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the server returns a response first, you can use `fsockopen()` but other methods are also available like using the [operating system shell](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) so you can `ping`.

```
function is_connectable(string $host, int $port=80, int $timeout=3){
    if($fp = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout)){
        return fclose($fp) || true;
    }

    return false;
}

$host = "mysql.someserver.com";
$port = 3306;
$user = "username";
$pass = "mypassword";
$mydb = "mydatabase";

if(is_connectable($host, $port)){
    try{
      $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$mydb", $user, $pass);
    } catch(Exception $e){
      die($e->getMessage());
    }
} else {
    die("mysql server '$host' is down");
}
```

There is also use the timeout from the database driver directly:

- [`PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) for PDO
- [`MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php) for MySQLi